# What are "tensides"?

Tags: surfactants

I was reading about chemicals that control pore size of polyurethane foams and there it was mentioned that "tensides" decrease pore size. What are tensides? I assume it's the opposite of a surfactant, that is, it increases surface tension, but that is just my guess. I have no idea what it actually is.

I tried to Google it but strangely I just got bunch of "surfactant" results even through I wrote it just tensides. Some German site when translated from German to English changed the word tenside to surfactant, so I don't know if it is different class of chemicals or just a German word for surfactant. From the original article where I saw the word, it was written in a way as to suggest that they both are different from each other.

Comment: See also: [What is the opposite of a surfactant?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/what-is-the-opposite-of-a-surfactant?rq=1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't remember to have seen the term *tensid* outside the context of the German language.

The term is typically applied to agents that decrease the surface *tension* (hence *tensid*) of water. Note that the logic behind the English equivalent *surfactant* is just the same.

So, in summary *tensid* and *surfactant* mean the same.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the term "tensider" (likely meaning "surfactants") on labels in Swedish too, this is probably because Swedish is a Germanic language. All sources I could find seem to confirm that it is just a word for surfactants. I have seen the word used in German as well.